# R help needed with plotting simple graphs

Tags: r, plot

```
diamonds <- read.table('Test1.csv', head=T)
plot(diamonds$carat, diamonds$price, xlab="carat", ylab="price")
```

Data is correctly imported. But I am not being able to create the plot in (1) because of:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Some of the data is:

```
ID  carat   colour  clarity certification   VariablePrice   Price
1   0.3     D      VS2       GIA                 1302   3.114610984
2   0.3     E      VS1       GIA                 1510   3.178976947
3   0.3     G      VVS1      GIA                 1510   3.178976947
4   0.3     G      VS1       GIA                 1260   3.100370545
5   0.31    D      VS1       GIA                 1641   3.215108581
6   0.31    E     VS1        GIA                 1555   3.191730393
7   0.31    F     VS1        GIA                 1427   3.154423973
8   0.31    G     VVS2       GIA                 1427   3.154423973
9   0.31    H     VS2        GIA                 1126   3.051538391
```

Please kindly assist with data plotting including any necessary R code. Thanks

Comment: Could you post `summary(diamonds)`? Also please work on the formatting. Edit your question and put your code in code blocks either by pushing the `{}` button or by indenting if 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that you're calling the columns by their proper names. R is **case-sensitive**; so given the sample data you provided, `diamonds$price` doesn't work, but `diamonds$Price` will. So try:

`plot(x=diamonds$carat, y=diamonds$Price, xlab="carat", ylab="price")`

Comment: You could also use the formula interface to `plot(...)` as in `plot(Price~carat,diamonds)`, which sets the axis titles automatically.